# How to login and pass token to WebAPI2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I added the WebApi2 to my MVC application and I can successfully call my API through a browser.  If the user is not authenticated it brings up my standard login screen and then works.

But I really want to call the api as a REST api from a mobile app.  I added the following code to startup that I found while searching.  But I have no idea how to actually login through a url, or pass and use a token in my calls.

I tried for example myurl/api/Account/ExternalLogin, but I get invalid request.

```
        PublicClientId = "self";
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            // Note: Remove the following line before you deploy to production:
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };
```

So the question is, how to I actually use the REST api calls, or do I need to put additional code in my controller.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have your API configured to use OAuth .. you can use following code to get access token

```
        /// <summary>
        /// This method uses the OAuth Client Credentials Flow to get an Access Token to provide
        /// Authorization to the APIs.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
        {
            if (accessToken == null)
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var email = "xyz"
                var password = "abc";
                var clientId = "123"
                var clientSecret = "456";

                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);

                // We want the response to be JSON.
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                // Build up the data to POST.
                List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

                postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type",    "password"));
                postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id",     clientId));
                postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", clientSecret));
                postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username",      email));
                postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password",      password));

                FormUrlEncodedContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);

                // Post to the Server and parse the response.
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("Token", content);
                string jsonString            = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                object responseData          = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);

                // return the Access Token.
                accessToken = ((dynamic)responseData).access_token;
            }

            return accessToken;
        }
```

and once you have access token, you can use something like following to pass access token to API call

```
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                // Add the Authorization header with the AccessToken.
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken); // accessToken is returned from GetAccessToken function

                // create the URL string.
                string url = string.Format("API url goes here");

                // make the request
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);

                // parse the response and return the data.
                string jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                object responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
                return (dynamic)responseData;
            }
```